# Angular App build failed while building in Electron

Tags: angular, electron

I am facing a build failed error while building an angular project to an electron.
 when I use this command `npm run electron-build` i got this :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 
'G:\pos\node_modules\electron'
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 
'G:\pos\node_modules\electron'
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(60,49): error TS2339: Property 'fireConfig' 
does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pos@0.0.0 electron-build: `ng build --prod && electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pos@0.0.0 electron-build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-17T15_49_13_982Z- 
debug.log
```

I deleted node modules and reinstalled but I got still the same error

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you don't have `fireConfig` in your `environment.prod.ts`.

In your `environment.prod.ts` file add `fireConfig` that you have used in your `environemnt.ts`.